# How to list Content A nodes on Content B's page using Entity Reference fields and Views (with Paragraph field Bundles attached)

Tags: views, entities, paragraphs

I have **Content A (Music Albums)** with **entity reference fields** referencing **Content B (Musician)**.

I want to display a view on **Content B (Musician)** page that displays every **Album (Content A)** they are 'tagged' on. Basically using entity reference fields in place of taxonomy (per StackExchange suggestion).

**Content A (Album)** has a View displaying various info such as *album image, album name, record label etc...* and an **Entity Reference** field  referencing **Content B (Musician)**. When clicked it takes me to the node page of that Musician.

On the **Musician's (Content B)** page I want to have a View displaying all **Albums (Content A)** they appear on (tagged via entity reference field).

Finally, Getting the entity reference fields attached to a Paragraph Bundle to relate to **Content B (Musician)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply under **Advanced** (far right), for **Contextual Filter** add your entity reference field. In my test, I called it "Made by" `field_made_by`.

**Note:** The view preview will be blank as the view edit page does not have an ID. Just place to your Musician page and it will show up then.

[image]

---

> However, when using paragraphs module to add node bundles is more
>   complex because technically a paragraph bundle is it's own entity, so
>   Content A references a Paragraph Bundle with an entity reference field
>   within its bundle (LOL). It gets pretty complicating. Any help with
>   that?

Then make a view of Paragraph and not of Content.

[image]

Then add relationship of `Paragraph referenced from field_paragraph` (paragraph field)

Then in contextual filter add `field_made_by` (entity reference field).

Comment: Thanks that seemed to do the trick for entity reference fields on the content page. However, when using paragraphs module to add node bundles is more complex because technically a paragraph bundle is it's own entity, so Content A references a Paragraph Bundle with an entity reference field within its bundle (LOL). It gets pretty complicating.

Any help with that?

Comment: @TimJones such crucial info should never be left out when asking a question. Please edit your question.

Comment: Ya thanks. I couldn't figure out how to tie that module into the main question. However, using your above help, I figured it out. by adding a relationship to the paragraph bundle, then a contextual filter to the bundle field i need.